# VS 2019 - Toggle line comment shortcut not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Under `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard` is the setting `Edit.ToggleLineComment`

I can see that the shortcut for the selected command is set to `Ctrl + / (Global)`

I'd expect that when I pressed the shortcut, any selected code would be commented out, however, when pressing the shortcut nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting to see not many people are talking about this. I am also suffering from the same issue in VS2019 and it's pretty annoying. Remapping the thing does nothing and when I try to use the command, it tells me "The Key Combination ... is bound to command (Toggle Line Comment) which is not currently available.".

Comment: Still having this issue. I'm using a Mac.

Comment: It's related to newlines in the selected block. Didn't figure it out though.

Comment: It's nearly 2023 and it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 34):

For the default keyboard mapping scheme, `Ctrl + /` is assigned to `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.GenerateDocumentationComments`. Make sure to remove this shortcut first.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked for me. Vs2019 V16.11.7 
Thank you!

Comment: Same fix works in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 11):

Change mapping from default to visual studio code.

tools->options->Environment->keyboard

beside reset button, change the mapping

Answer (score 0):

I had had a conflicting shortcut with GitHub Copilot. You can change it or remove it:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+/",
    "command": "-github.copilot.acceptCursorPanelSolution",
    "when": "github.copilot.activated && github.copilot.panelVisible"
}
```