# Visual Studio 2022 - Edit.ToggleLineComment not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to reassign Edit.ToggleLineComment to `Ctrl+/` so I can easily comment and uncomment. However, it's not working. This is what my keybind looks like currently and hitting `Ctrl+/` does nothing.

[image]

I found this other post, but I've checked that `Ctrl+/` is only bound to Edit.ToggleLineComment at the moment. This post is also about VS2019, while I'm working with VS2022, though I'm not sure if that makes a difference.
[VS 2019 - Toggle line comment shortcut not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57695846/vs-2019-toggle-line-comment-shortcut-not-working)

Comment: Try selecting "Text Editor" instead of "Global" for "Use new shortcut in".

Comment: This may also vary by language.  Visual Studio added the Toggle Line Comment command relatively recently (maybe VS2017?).  If the language supported Comment Selection and Uncomment Selection, they may have overlooked implementing a command handler for the newer Toggle Line Comment.  But the keybinding context ("Use shortcut in") is more likely.